# Highlight duplicate results based on values from two Datatables columns

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using this code to highlight the lines that have the same value in the FTTH column of the table:

```
function highlight() {

    var duplicate = false;

    var rows = $("#tableos").DataTable().rows({ search: 'applied' }).nodes();
    $.each(rows, function (index, value) {
        var $current = $(this).children(":nth-child(9)");
        var $next = (index !== rows.length)
            ? $(rows[index + 1]).children(":nth-child(9)")
            : $('<td/>');

        if ($current.text() === $next.text() && !duplicate) {
            duplicate = true;
            $current.parent().children().addClass("info");
            if(index > 0){
                $(rows[index-1]).children().css("border-bottom", "1px solid #333");
            }
        } else if ($current.text() === $next.text() && duplicate) {
            $current.parent().children().addClass("info");
        } else if ($current.text() !== $next.text() && duplicate) {
            $current.parent().children().addClass("info");
            $current.parent().children().css("border-bottom", "1px solid #333");
            duplicate = false;
        } else {
            $current.parent().children().removeClass("info");
            $current.parent().children().css("border-bottom", "");
        }
    });
}
```

It works as expected, see below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9TBv.png)

But I would also like to filter the city column, so that this does not happen:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UbcG.png)

Could anyone tell me how I can solve this situation?

Comment: Quick approach: Can you concatenate the values - for example: `var $currentText = $(this).children(":nth-child(5)").text() + $(this).children(":nth-child(9)");`. And the same for `var $nextText`. And then compare these two new variables. If that is not what you need, I think I may have misunderstood the problem.

Comment: Noticed a typo in my original note: I missed the `.text()` from the column 9 clause.